# filterfirst and filterlast function with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Let's say we have an array of products as shown below, products are ordered by name and then by pricing.
How do I get the cheapest products or the most expensive products per category using lodash?
We need something like `filterfirst` and `filterlast` function.

```
[
    {
      "productId": "123456",
      "name": "Daiper",
      "category": "Home",
      "store": "store1",
      "pricing": 10
    },
    {
      "productId": "123457",
      "name": "Daiper",
      "category": "Home",
      "store": "store2",
      "pricing": 20
    },
    {
      "productId": "123458",
      "name": "Daiper",
      "category": "Home",
      "store": "store3",
      "pricing": 30
    },
    {
      "productId": "123466",
      "name": "Paint",
      "category": "Home",
      "store": "store2",
      "pricing": 25
    },
    {
      "productId": "123467",
      "name": "Paint",
      "category": "Home",
      "store": "store1",
      "pricing": 36
    },
    {
      "productId": "123468",
      "name": "Paint",
      "category": "Home",
      "store": "store3",
      "pricing": 80
    }
]
```

Comment: How about pure js solution?

Comment: `chain` -> `filter` -> `initial(offset)` or `chain` -> `filter` -> `slice( offset * -1)` will do what you want. Due to lazy evaluation, you won't get the whole chain executed but just as many things as you want - so, in the first example, the filtering will stop once `offset` items is reached. The second one might be rewritten to be the same as the first but with an extra `reverse` thrown in. `takeWhile` and `takeRightWhile` might also be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) the items by the `name` property, and then [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) the array of group to the 1st or last item of each group:

```js
function filterGroups(groupIdProp, predicate) {
  return function(arr) {
    return _(arr)
      .groupBy(groupIdProp)
      .map(predicate)
      .values();
  }
}

var filterFirst = filterGroups('name', function(group) {
  return group[0];
});

var filterLast = filterGroups('name', function(group) {
  return group[group.length - 1];
})

var arr = [{
  "productId": "123456",
  "name": "Daiper",
  "category": "Home",
  "store": "store1",
  "pricing": 10
}, {
  "productId": "123457",
  "name": "Daiper",
  "category": "Home",
  "store": "store2",
  "pricing": 20
}, {
  "productId": "123458",
  "name": "Daiper",
  "category": "Home",
  "store": "store3",
  "pricing": 30
}, {
  "productId": "123466",
  "name": "Paint",
  "category": "Home",
  "store": "store2",
  "pricing": 25
}, {
  "productId": "123467",
  "name": "Paint",
  "category": "Home",
  "store": "store1",
  "pricing": 36
}, {
  "productId": "123468",
  "name": "Paint",
  "category": "Home",
  "store": "store3",
  "pricing": 80
}];

console.log('first', filterFirst(arr));

console.log('last', filterLast(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```